# Gitlab CI fetching latest added version update on master

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have 2 Gitlab CI jobs which run on master.

1. Versioning
2. Deployment

Suppose initial version is 1.0.0
Versioning jobs runs first and calculates the new version (say 1.1.0). Then in the job I update the `pyproject.toml` with new version and publish the package. Then add a commit to update the value in master.

Now when I run deployment job I my `pyproject.toml` file i get the old version ie. `1.0.0`. But here i want to get the new version `1.1.0`. Now i can use gitlab api to fetch the `pyproject.toml` file from master and use it this will give me `1.1.0`. But problem with this is suppose after some time i come back and restart this deployment then the gitlab api will fetch the current latest version in master which will be something like say 1.10.0 instead of getting `1.1.0`.

(I think fresh cloning in deployment job could work but it should not do a fresh cloning on restarting the job)

Comment: Have you considered dynamic versioning with something like [setuptools_scm](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm)?

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/deployment_safety.html#prevent-outdated-deployment-jobs

Comment: Here for me versioning is not the issue. Getting the updated version in the deployment job is the issue. If i use dynamic versioning when i rerun the old deployment the latest version will be taken

Answer (score 0):

> (I think fresh cloning in deployment job could work but it should not do a fresh cloning on restarting the job)

Gitlab always clones by specific SHA1 hash - not by ref name. So when you actually just ***restart a job***, you will get the exact same revision of the repository.

It's only when you start a ***new pipeline*** specifying a ref name, that you get a new revision.

> Now i can use gitlab api to fetch the pyproject.toml file from master

That kind of got things backwards. You should not fetch additional configuration files from outside the repository you are currently building. That is simply asking for trouble.

Make sure that versions are always either pinned in a configuration file which is part of the repository you are currently running the pipeline for, or that the configuration file is communicated as an ***artifact*** by the previous job in the pipeline.

The later rule actually applies to ***ALL*** package management systems and CI. Whenever you have any externally visible dependencies and versions, the first job touching the dependency tree needs to ***pin*** the exact revisions and versions to be used  by the remainder of the pipeline. That's the only way you will ever get at least repeatable jobs executions (e.g. for a repeatable deployment).

Comment: problem here is when i merge my merge request to master the publish job is triggered. This publish job find the new version and add the commit with the new version in master. Now publish job will have a updated version file and i can use artifacts so that it reaches the next deployment. Problem in case the artifact gets deleted or expired then i will get the old version in deployment.